# Selenium: method main requires 1 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Test annotation

Tags: java, testng

While executing the script using TestNG, it is skipping the main. Below is a sample code, which is similar to mine. If i remove `String[] args`, then the code is working with TestNG, but running as java application option is removed. How can i overcome this?

```
Package tests;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
public class SearchText {
    public void createzoo(String[] args) {  
        String[] elems = {"lion", "tiger", "duck"};  
        System.out.println(elems[0]);
        System.out.println(elems[1]);
        System.out.println(elems[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with selenium. Try to use only appropriate tags so as not to pollute other tags unnecessarily. Also, what's the IDE (and the version) you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

When you want to execute a Java Project you have 2 ways to do so:

1. Execute the Java file which contains the `main` method as:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   ```

   Your Java program will start executing from Line 1 within `main` method.
2. If you have integrated `TestNG` libraries to your Java Project you have got a new approach to execute your Java Project. Once you integrate `TestNG` there is absolutely no need of writing  `main` method as previous case. In this case you need to execute the Class file which contains the `@Test` Annotation of  `TestNG` as a `TestNG Test`. TestNG will execute your methods marked with `@Test` Annotations one by one as per the logic you specify. Once you execute your Java Project as a `TestNG Test` a xml file is generated by the name `testng-customsuite.xml`.
3. Next you can use your IDE feature `Convert to TestNG` to convert your Java Project to a `TestNG` specific Project. On doing that you will observe an xml file by the name `testng.xml` being created at your Project Level. Now using `testng.xml` you can also be able to execute the Project as a `TestNG Suite`

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `@Test` on a class, then it means that all methods of the class are test methods, included `main`.

If a test method has params, then TestNG must know how to inject them.

Currently, there is no way to exclude some method via annotations and an issue related issue already exists: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1405

As an alternative, you can only annotate methods instead of class and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This error "XYZ method requires 1 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Test annotation" is encountered when there is misuse of @Test annotation in the code.

In your case, you can either run the application as java application or as TestNG application. When using TestNG , main is not required and you can use run as TestNG.  When running as java application, main method would be required.

> > > > > > If i remove String[] args, then the code is working with TestNG, but running as java application option is removed.

When you remove String[] args, it will not be considered main method required for running java application. It is just any regular method. Hence it is working with TestNG but run as java application option is not applicable.